# How can we send notification from specific app while working with FCM notification in django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing a website where I have 3 fcm apps. so that i have 3 credentials file of different projects. Now i have initialize three of them. But the problem is. I am unable to configure how to send notification from desire app. as you see below.
this is the list of app that i initialize.

{'[DEFAULT]': <firebase_admin.App object at 0x7fa5e2ce2350>, 'meidan_userpanel': <firebase_admin.App object at 0x7fa5e2ce05b0>,'meidan_merchant': <firebase_admin.App object at 0x7fa5e3uc05b1>}

here is my code.
def mobile_push_notes(notification=None,registration_tokens=None,file_name=None):
print("file_name == ",file_name)

```
if not file_name:
    return
if not registration_tokens:
    return

if isinstance(registration_tokens, str):
    registration_tokens=[registration_tokens]

try:
    if not firebase_admin._apps:
        cred = credentials.Certificate(f'{file_name}.json')
        if not initializers[file_name] :
            initializers[file_name] = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

except Exception as e:
    print("Mobile push file not found! or ",str(e))
    return None

print("initializers  ============================",firebase_admin._apps)

message_body = remove_html(notification["message"])

if not registration_tokens:
    return None
    
try:
    data = notification["data"]
except:
    data="{}"


message = messaging.MulticastMessage(
    data={
        'id':str(notification["id"]),
        "sender":str(notification["sender"]),
        "message":str(notification["message"]),
        "title":str(notification["title"]),
        "is_merchant_side":str(notification["is_merchant_side"]),
        "is_userpanel_side":str(notification["is_userpanel_side"]),
        "category":str(notification["category"]),
        "resolution_reply":str(notification["resolution_reply"]),
        "create_time":str(notification["create_time"]),
        "is_remove":str(notification["is_remove"]),
        "data":data
    },
    
    notification=messaging.Notification(
        title=notification["title"],
        body=str(message_body)
    ),
    android=messaging.AndroidConfig(
        ttl=datetime.timedelta(days=7),
        # autoCancel=False,
        priority='normal',
        notification=messaging.AndroidNotification(
            icon='icon.jpg',
            color='#f45342',
            
        ),
    ),
    apns=messaging.APNSConfig(
        payload=messaging.APNSPayload(
            aps=messaging.Aps(),
        ),
    ),
    tokens=registration_tokens,

)
response = messaging.send_multicast(message)
```

here i want to specify my app where i want to send notification.
response = messaging.send_multicast(message)